Value getting lost in the pipeline while training a GPT-2 model
I'm writing a project to train a GPT-2 model, due to the structure of the dataset and it containing negative examples, data passed through had to be modified slightly such that the "negative" flag exists for all entries. The variable negative_maskis given to dataset entries with the nagtive flag set to true.
The dataset class is:
class CustomTextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, examples, block_size=128):
        self.examples = examples
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.block_size = block_size

        texts = [example['text'] for example in examples]
        negative_masks = [example['negative'] for example in examples]

        self.encodings = tokenizer(texts, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=self.block_size, return_tensors='pt')
        self.negative_masks = torch.tensor(negative_masks, dtype=torch.float)

        print(f"Encodings: {self.encodings}")
        print(f"Negative masks: {self.negative_masks}")

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: val[idx] for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['negative_mask'] = self.negative_masks[idx]

        if 'negative_mask' not in item: #debug, passed
            print(f"Error: negative_mask is missing in dataset item {idx}")
        print(f"Dataset item {idx}: {item}")
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings['input_ids'])

And the debug lines supports that negative_mask is present, as per the debug line:
Negative masks: tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,

However by the time we get to the data collector class:
class CustomDataCollator:
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, mlm=False, mlm_probability=0.15):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.mlm = mlm
        self.mlm_probability = mlm_probability
        self.data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=mlm, mlm_probability=mlm_probability)
        
    def __call__(self, features):
        print("Features received by CustomDataCollator:", features)
        for i, feature in enumerate(features): #debug, 
            if 'negative_mask' not in feature:
                print(f"Feature {i} is missing negative_mask: {feature}")
                raise ValueError(f"negative_mask is missing in feature {i}: {feature}") # raised here -----

        input_ids = torch.stack([f['input_ids'] for f in features])
        attention_mask = torch.stack([f['attention_mask'] for f in features])
        negative_mask = torch.tensor([f['negative_mask'] for f in features], dtype=torch.float)

        batch = {
            'input_ids': input_ids,
            'attention_mask': attention_mask,
            'negative_mask': negative_mask
        }

        if 'labels' in features[0]:
            batch['labels'] = torch.stack([f['labels'] for f in features])

        print(f"Batch prepared in CustomDataCollator: {batch}")
        return batch

line: raise ValueError(f"negative_mask is missing in feature {i}: {feature}") # raised , is raised every time indicating somewhere in the pipeline negative_mask is being dropped, supported by the exception, negative_mask seems to have magically vanished:
ValueError: negative_mask is missing in feature 0: {'input_ids': tensor([   70,  4024, 10163,    11, 23624,  6188,    25,  1210,   826,  9087,
        20064,    11,  5529,  1944, 20334,   685,    45,  7156, 37045,    60,
        50256, 50256, 50256, 50256, 50256, 50256, 50256, 50256, 50256, 50256]), 'attention_mask': tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])}

I have tried by adding a debug line at every point of the data flow to make sure that negative_mask is present, I have narrowed down the point of faliure is to be between the CustomDataCollector class and CustomTextDataset class but I do not have an explanation as to why the label is getting lost.
